# forEach в вычесляемые свойства Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как использовать данный метод вв вычисляемых свойствах ? `forEach` там не работает... мне нужно сложить все значения и вернуть результат

```
summPaysActiveContract(pays){
                let sum = 0
                pays.forEach(function (value, key) {
                    sum += value.pay
                });
                return sum
            },
```

Comment: а что вы получаете в pays? Эт оч странно что forEach не работать
как вариан попробуйте через цикл for просуммировать

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вычисляемые свойства (computed) не принимают параметров. Вы можете перенести ваш `summPaysActiveContract` в методы (methods) и все будет работать.
Либо, если это возможно, брать pays из вашего компонента.
То есть так:

```
summPaysActiveContract(){
  let sum = 0
  this.pays.forEach(function (value, key) {
      sum += value.pay
  });
  return sum
},
```